# MT7601U dongle usb wifi installed and detected wifi but doesn't work it Ubuntu Freezes

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, internet, usb-modem

I'm trying install MT7630E driver but installation failed.

So I bought  Mt7601U USB WiFi Dongle

I had installed its package from this website: https://github.com/terence-deng/mt7601u.git

I compiled it without errors, then I plugged usb driver and I loaded,the wifi appears and I can connect on it.

But when I oppen firefox or google chrome, ubuntu freezes and blocked, I also try using wifi only in terminal when I applied this command : `sudo apt-get update`, Ubuntu freezes too.

what should I do? I really need wifi in my laptop.

Thank you in advance.

NB: some informations

kernel (uname -r): `4.4.0-148-generic`

> > 

```
 lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b40a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0e8d:763f MediaTek Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


 root@dounia-pc:/home/dounia/mt7601u#   sudo ./load.sh
    [ 2883.033553] rtusb init rtusbSTA --->
    [ 2883.033797] 
    [ 2883.033797] 
    [ 2883.033797] === pAd = ffffc90001821000, size = 895216 ===
    [ 2883.033797] 
    [ 2883.033928] <-- RTMPAllocTxRxRingMemory, Status=0
    [ 2883.034105] <-- RTMPAllocAdapterBlock, Status=0
    [ 2883.034111] RTMP_COM_IoctlHandle():pAd->BulkOutEpAddr=0x8
    [ 2883.034113] RTMP_COM_IoctlHandle():pAd->BulkOutEpAddr=0x4
    [ 2883.034116] RTMP_COM_IoctlHandle():pAd->BulkOutEpAddr=0x5
    [ 2883.034118] RTMP_COM_IoctlHandle():pAd->BulkOutEpAddr=0x6
    [ 2883.034121] RTMP_COM_IoctlHandle():pAd->BulkOutEpAddr=0x7
    [ 2883.034123] RTMP_COM_IoctlHandle():pAd->BulkOutEpAddr=0x9
    [ 2883.034463] NVM is EFUSE
    [ 2883.034468] Endpoint(8) is for In-band Command
    [ 2883.034471] Endpoint(4) is for WMM0 AC0
    [ 2883.034474] Endpoint(5) is for WMM0 AC1
    [ 2883.034476] Endpoint(6) is for WMM0 AC2
    [ 2883.034479] Endpoint(7) is for WMM0 AC3
    [ 2883.034482] Endpoint(9) is for WMM1 AC0
    [ 2883.034484] Endpoint(84) is for Data-In
    [ 2883.034487] Endpoint(85) is for Command Rsp
    [ 2883.035828] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtusbSTA
    [ 2883.039133] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018a4688!
    [ 2883.039139] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018a46b8!
    [ 2883.039142] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018a46e8!
    [ 2883.039145] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018a4658!
    [ 2883.039149] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018a45c8!
    [ 2883.039152] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018a45f8!
    [ 2883.039155] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001837bd0!
    [ 2883.039158] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001823a78!
    [ 2883.039161] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001823ab0!
    [ 2883.039163] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001837c80!
    [ 2883.039166] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001826600!
    [ 2883.039169] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001825c78!
    [ 2883.039171] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018265c8!
    [ 2883.039174] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018268e8!
    [ 2883.039177] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001826638!
    [ 2883.039179] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001826670!
    [ 2883.039182] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018266a8!
    [ 2883.039186] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001837b70!
    [ 2883.039189] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001837c50!
    [ 2883.039210] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001826940!
    [ 2883.039213] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001826970!
    [ 2883.039216] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018269a0!
    [ 2883.039219] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018269d0!
    [ 2883.055761] no file read method
    [ 2883.055767] Read file "/etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/RT2870STA.dat" failed(errCode=-1)!
    [ 2883.055770] 1. Phy Mode = 6
    [ 2883.055820] 2. Phy Mode = 6
    [ 2883.055823] NVM is Efuse and its size =1d[1e0-1fc] 
    [ 2883.061938] ERROR!!! MT7601 E2PROM: WRONG VERSION 0xd, should be 12
    [ 2883.071062] 3. Phy Mode = 6
    [ 2883.071065] AntCfgInit: primary/secondary ant 0/1
    [ 2883.270483] ---> InitFrequencyCalibration
    [ 2883.270487] InitFrequencyCalibrationMode:Unknow mode = 3
    [ 2883.270489] InitFrequencyCalibration: frequency offset in the EEPROM = 85(0x55)
    [ 2883.270490] <--- InitFrequencyCalibration
    [ 2883.270494] RTMPSetPhyMode: channel is out of range, use first channel=1 
    [ 2883.270497] MCS Set = 00 00 00 00 00
    [ 2883.280448] <==== rt28xx_init, Status=0
    [ 2883.280858] 0x1300 = 000a4200
    [ 2883.280859] RTMPDrvOpen(1):Check if PDMA is idle!
    [ 2883.280902] RTMPDrvOpen(2):Check if PDMA is idle!
    [ 2883.283758] AsicSendCmdToAndes: !fRTMP_ADAPTER_MCU_SEND_IN_BAND_CMD && fRTMP_ADAPTER_IDLE_RADIO_OFF
    [ 2883.283910] AsicSendCmdToAndes: !fRTMP_ADAPTER_MCU_SEND_IN_BAND_CMD && fRTMP_ADAPTER_IDLE_RADIO_OFF
    [ 2883.286661] AsicSendCmdToAndes: !fRTMP_ADAPTER_MCU_SEND_IN_BAND_CMD && fRTMP_ADAPTER_IDLE_RADIO_OFF
    [ 2883.286663] AsicSendCmdToAndes: !fRTMP_ADAPTER_MCU_SEND_IN_BAND_CMD && fRTMP_ADAPTER_IDLE_RADIO_OFF
    [ 2883.286664] AsicSendCmdToAndes: !fRTMP_ADAPTER_MCU_SEND_IN_BAND_CMD && fRTMP_ADAPTER_IDLE_RADIO_OFF
    [ 2883.286851] AsicSendCmdToAndes: !fRTMP_ADAPTER_MCU_SEND_IN_BAND_CMD && fRTMP_ADAPTER_IDLE_RADIO_OFF
    [ 2883.287062] ERROR!!! RTMPSetTimer failed, Halt in Progress!
    [ 2883.497930] AsicSendCmdToAndes: !fRTMP_ADAPTER_MCU_SEND_IN_BAND_CMD && fRTMP_ADAPTER_IDLE_RADIO_OFF
    [ 2883.497972] unlink cmd rsp urb
    [ 2883.580693] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018a4688!
    [ 2883.580695] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018a46b8!
    [ 2883.580697] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018a46e8!
    [ 2883.580698] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018a4658!
    [ 2883.580700] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018a45c8!
    [ 2883.580701] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018a45f8!
    [ 2883.580702] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001837bd0!
    [ 2883.580704] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001823a78!
    [ 2883.580705] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001823ab0!
    [ 2883.580706] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001837c80!
    [ 2883.580707] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001826600!
    [ 2883.580708] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001825c78!
    [ 2883.580709] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018265c8!
    [ 2883.580710] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018268e8!
    [ 2883.580711] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001826638!
    [ 2883.580712] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001826670!
    [ 2883.580713] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018266a8!
    [ 2883.580715] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001837b70!
    [ 2883.580717] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001837c50!
    [ 2883.580727] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001826940!
    [ 2883.580728] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc90001826970!
    [ 2883.580730] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018269a0!
    [ 2883.580731] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc900018269d0!
    [ 2883.590956] no file read method
    [ 2883.590959] Read file "/etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/RT2870STA.dat" failed(errCode=-1)!
    [ 2883.590961] 1. Phy Mode = 6
    [ 2883.590963] 2. Phy Mode = 6
    [ 2883.590965] NVM is Efuse and its size =1d[1e0-1fc] 
    [ 2883.594548] ERROR!!! MT7601 E2PROM: WRONG VERSION 0xd, should be 12
    [ 2883.603878] 3. Phy Mode = 6
    [ 2883.603881] AntCfgInit: primary/secondary ant 0/1
    [ 2883.801624] ---> InitFrequencyCalibration
    [ 2883.801630] InitFrequencyCalibrationMode:Unknow mode = 3
    [ 2883.801633] InitFrequencyCalibration: frequency offset in the EEPROM = 85(0x55)
    [ 2883.801635] <--- InitFrequencyCalibration
    [ 2883.801643] MCS Set = 00 00 00 00 00
    [ 2883.811600] <==== rt28xx_init, Status=0
    [ 2883.812084] 0x1300 = 000a4200
    [ 2883.812088] RTMPDrvOpen(1):Check if PDMA is idle!
    [ 2883.812146] RTMPDrvOpen(2):Check if PDMA is idle!
    [ 2883.837520] /home/dounia/mt7601u/src/os/linux/../../common/cmm_asic.c:2123 assert KeyIdx < 4failed
    [ 2883.837721] /home/dounia/mt7601u/src/os/linux/../../common/cmm_asic.c:2123 assert KeyIdx < 4failed
    [ 2885.437675] ===>rt_ioctl_giwscan. 1(1) BSS returned, data->length = 228
    [ 2885.479778] ==>rt_ioctl_siwfreq::SIOCSIWFREQ(Channel=10)
    [ 2885.505056] PeerBeaconAtJoinAction(): Set CentralChannel=10
    [ 2907.454893] Bulk In Failed. Status=-71, BIIdx=0x7, BIRIdx=0x7, actual_length= 0x0
    [ 2907.455005] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 6
    [ 2907.455462] rtusb_disconnect: unregister usbnet usb-0000:00:14.0-1
    [ 2907.455470] RtmpOSNetDevDetach(): RtmpOSNetDeviceDetach(), dev->name=ra0!
    [ 2907.464931] CMDTHREAD_RESET_BULK_IN: Cannot do bulk in because flags(0x300a0542) on !
    [ 2907.576542] ---> RTMPFreeTxRxRingMemory
    [ 2907.576563] <--- RTMPFreeTxRxRingMemory
    [ 2907.576565] reg_atomic get failed(ret=-1)
    [ 2907.576625]  RTUSB disconnect successfully
    [ 2907.816679] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
    [ 2909.912764] usbcore: deregistering interface driver rtusbSTA
    [ 2909.912823] <--- rtusb exit
    [ 2915.773156] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
    [ 2915.912232] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=7601
    [ 2915.912236] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
    [ 2915.912239] usb 1-2: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
    [ 2915.912241] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: MediaTek
    [ 2915.912243] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 1.0
    [ 2915.916853] mt7601Usta: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
```

> > ```
> >  ifconfig
> > ```

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 78:24:af:6c:61:ab  
          inet adr:192.168.1.39  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
          adr inet6: fd80::7a24:afff:fe6c:61ab/64 Scope:Global
          adr inet6: fd80::5d2:5e5b:61b3:dbe3/64 Scope:Global
          adr inet6: fe80::7a24:afff:fe6c:61ab/64 Scope:Lien
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:14565 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12677 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          Octets reçus:4693358 (4.6 MB) Octets transmis:3085059 (3.0 MB)

lo        Link encap:Boucle locale  
          inet adr:127.0.0.1  Masque:255.0.0.0
          adr inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Hôte
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:4755 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4755 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1 
          Octets reçus:414412 (414.4 KB) Octets transmis:414412 (414.4 KB)

ra0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:e5:17:02:ee:95  
          inet adr:192.168.1.42  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
          adr inet6: fe80::22e5:17ff:fe02:ee95/64 Scope:Lien
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:1231 erreurs:0 :3 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:136 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          Octets reçus:311554 (311.5 KB) Octets transmis:25601 (25.6 KB)
```

Comment: Try it with the Ubuntu 20.04 ISO

Comment: @Jeremy31 I have Ubuntu 14

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 is hopelessly out of date and no longer receives crucial security updates. mt7601u is built in to present versions and no longer needs to be compiled from source.